# $_SESSION error:Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php

Hi sorry I am just a baby in PHP. I want to get the value of `$_SESSION['username']` but it gives me this error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Please see my code below. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username']='andrew';
$_SESSION['password']='pass';

$session=count($_SESSION);
echo "There are {$session} current sessions!";
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION[0]; //I want an output "andrew" but it fails.

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `0`? It would be `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['username']`??

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261158/6107715

Comment: You are treating `$_SESSION` like an indexed array (numbers) instead of an associative array (keys).

Comment: Also, your session is scoped by the cookie. You can't find the number of active sessions that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['username']='andrew'; 
$_SESSION['password']='pass';

$session=count($_SESSION); 
echo "There are {$session} current sessions!"; echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['username']; //I want an output "andrew" but it fails.

?>
```